# Server replication HA

Tags: redundancy

I have a server connected to a switch, to ensure the server has HA, I want to replicate this server. To do so, do I connect the replicated server to the same switch as the primary server. Or do I need to have another switch to connect to second server Then link primary server to secondary switch and replicated server to primary switch?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is really a server configurations problem that is off-topic here. You could try to ask on [sf] for a business network. The switches do not really matter. The servers could be on the same switch, or across the world from each other. It depends on how you configure the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of HA is to have no single point of failure.

So, if you can fail over the entire server without any(!) data loss, the switch is your only SPOF (plus the uplink/firewall most likely). You'll need a second switch, and for best availability you connect each server to both switches. Then each switch to the uplink.